# Adding newly added fields in billing address and shipping address in order emails woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

In woocommerce order emails i want to custom fields added along with billing address.This is what i am tried.But it is giving error.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', array($this, 'woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address'), 10, 2);
function woo_custom_order_formatted_billing_address( $address , $WC_Order ) {
    $address = array(
        'first_name'       => $WC_Order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $WC_Order->billing_last_name,
        'company'          => $WC_Order->billing_company,
        'address_1'        => $WC_Order->billing_address_1,
        'address_2'        => $WC_Order->billing_address_2,
        'city'             => $WC_Order->billing_city,
        'state'            => $WC_Order->billing_state,
        'area'             => $WC_Order->billing_area,
        'emirates'         => $WC_Order->billing_emirates,
        'nearest_landmark' => $WC_Order->billing_nearest_landmark,
        'country'          => $WC_Order->billing_country,
        'email'            => $WC_Order->billing_email,
        'phone'            => $WC_Order->billing_phone,
    );
    return $address;
}
```

anybody pls help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You also are calling class function, where I don't see any class. 2nd parameter should be just the function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.917) filter instead of [`woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-order.html#source-view.906) to make sure you change the final result of the billing address.

For the `billing_area`, `billing_emirates` and `billing_nearest_landmark` custom fields you will need to get their respective values as order postmeta.

> The sorting of the fields will also be applied in the display of the
> billing address in the **backend** and in the **frontend**.
>
> The **billing phone** and **billing email** fields are added after the
> billing address in the `/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php` email
> template. So there is no need to add them otherwise they will show up double.

The following code should work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 'add_custom_field_billing_address', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_field_billing_address( $address, $raw_address, $order ) {

    $countries = new WC_Countries();
    // gets country and state codes
    $billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
    $billing_state = $order->get_billing_state();
    // gets the full names of the country and state
    $full_country = ( isset( $countries->countries[ $billing_country ] ) ) ? $countries->countries[ $billing_country ] : $billing_country;
    $full_state = ( $billing_country && $billing_state && isset( $countries->states[ $billing_country ][ $billing_state ] ) ) ? $countries->states[ $billing_country ][ $billing_state ] : $billing_state;

    $data = array(
        $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name(),
        $order->get_billing_company(),
        $order->get_billing_address_1(),
        $order->get_billing_address_2(),
        $order->get_billing_city(),
        $full_state,
        $order->get_meta( '_billing_area', true ),             // or $order->get_meta( 'billing_area', true )
        $order->get_meta( '_billing_emirates', true ),         // or $order->get_meta( 'billing_emirates', true )
        $order->get_meta( '_billing_nearest_landmark', true ), // or $order->get_meta( 'billing_nearest_landmark', true )
        $full_country,
    );

    // removes empty fields from the array
    $data = array_filter( $data );
    // create the billing address using the "<br/>" element as a separator
    $address = implode( '<br/>', $data );

    return $address;

}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*