# How to get all the fields with billing_* in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using **Woocommerce checkout field editor** and created several billing fields with name billing_*. For example billing_street, billing_town, billing_avenue, etc other than billing_address_1 and billing_address_2 which are predefined.

But while calling `$order->get_formatted_billing_address();` I am getting only billing_address_1 and billing_address_2.

Is there any way of calling all the value of the fields with the name `billing_*` in woocommerce.

Here's what I tried:

`$order->get_billing_address();`

But it didn't work!

Thank you in advance!

Screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge2f2.png)

This is the output I got:
[Screeshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge2f2.png)

At the same time,the other fields are showing in the orders page, but not as billing details. like here [image: not as billing details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the output of the `get_formatted_billing_address` method of the `WC_Order` class via the **`woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address`** filter hook (as you can see in [Adding newly added fields in billing address and shipping address in order emails woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536002/10447197)).

In your case, to add custom fields:

- `_billing_street`
- `_billing_town`
- `_billing_avenue`

you can use the following function:

> Feel free to change the sort order of the billing fields *(by changing
> the values of the `$data` array)*.

```
// adds the custom fields to the formatted billing address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 'add_custom_field_billing_address', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_field_billing_address( $address, $raw_address, $order ) {

   $countries = new WC_Countries();

   // gets country and state codes
   $billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
   $billing_state   = $order->get_billing_state();

   // gets the full names of the country and state
   $full_country = ( isset( $countries->countries[ $billing_country ] ) ) ? $countries->countries[ $billing_country ] : $billing_country;
   $full_state   = ( $billing_country && $billing_state && isset( $countries->states[ $billing_country ][ $billing_state ] ) ) ? $countries->states[ $billing_country ][ $billing_state ] : $billing_state;

   $data = array(
      $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name(),
      $order->get_billing_company(),
      $order->get_billing_address_1(),
      $order->get_billing_address_2(),
      $order->get_billing_postcode(),
      $order->get_billing_city(),
      wc_strtoupper( $full_state ),
      $order->get_meta( '_billing_street', true ),
      $order->get_meta( '_billing_town', true ),
      $order->get_meta( '_billing_avenue', true ),
   );

   // removes empty fields from the array
   $data = array_filter( $data );
   // create the billing address using the "<br/>" element as a separator
   $address = implode( '<br/>', $data );

   return $address;

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

> So now you can use the `$order->get_formatted_billing_address();`
> method to get the billing address formatted with the custom fields
> included.

Comment: that _ is confusing, do I need to add _billing_street? And where to put this code, in functions.php?

Comment: I put this code inside my theme's functions.php but it did not work. And I've used _ in the given code only. whereas in the field name its without underscore. No error showing.

Comment: A doubt arises. How were the custom billing fields added? Did you follow this guide? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-6

Comment: I am using the WooCommerce Checkout field editor plugin.

Comment: This was about billing details. Now how to fetch some other custom field such as I've added new_field. How can I fetch that?